# Does medic grenade hurt my teammates?

Tags: nuclear-dawn

I have been playing a medic for a couple of games and I like there [P-12 Poison Grenade](http://forums.interwavestudios.com/wiki/index.php/P-12_Poison_Grenade)/[U-23 Radiation Grenade](http://forums.interwavestudios.com/wiki/index.php/U-23_Radiation_Grenade), but I have managed to kill my self once or twice by running in to my own grenades deadly smoke, this results in -10 for committing suicide.

I have yet to kill anyone from my own team(as far as I know) have i just been lucky or does teammates not take damage from my grenade?

And if they can die from my grenade do I get a penalty of some kind for killing my own teammates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If friendly fire is disabled, all AoE effects only hurt you and the opponents, this includes P12 Grenades. The only way to hurt your teammates with FF off would be to become commander and throw buildings on their heads, otherwise they are completely safe from you.

With FF enabled, you should be able to kill anyone including teammates with P12s but i haven't tried that yet.

Comment: Are you sure about being able to kill people with building? I had a building being placed right next to me but I just got pushed to the side, but could be it was just the box opening animation that pushed me and not the actual building

Comment: I got killed by buildings landing on my head before, so i know that they can kill. However, i'm not sure wether those were allied or enemy buildings. In any case, when you die from falling buildings it counts as suicide.